# model.find({}) is not responding when I give the timeout as 5 minutes but it responds when the timeout is of 1 minute

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

i am working upon mongoose to list all the data from a collection in mongodb but i want the response to come after 5 minutes but it is not respondin when timeout value is 5 minute but it responds when timeout is 1 minute

```
router.get(routeIdentifier+'/list/:id', function(req, res, next) {
        model.find({}, function (err, objects) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                if (err) return res.send(err);            
                objects.push({id:req.params.id})
                return res.json(objects);
            },300000)       
        });
     })
```

;

Comment: What is the HTTP server timeout?

Comment: i dont have any idea about it, I am begginer in nodejs

Comment: Why do you want a delay of 5 minutes?

Comment: actually Its a testing project, in actual we need to hit third party api and that api will take around 5 minutes to respond so I was just testing with setTimeout()

Comment: This would be a bad idea. If it would take so much longer, you would better want to dump the response in async mode. You must never hog the HTTP-server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can sense, it is mainly due to the HTTP server timeout. It times out before sending the response from the database `model` .

The default timeout is 2 minutes as per the documentation here: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/http.html#http_server_settimeout_msecs_callback

Please note that `ExpressJS` sits on the top of built-in NodeJS HTTP server.

Try the following:

```
    let server = http.createServer( expressApp );

    server.setTimeout( 300000 );
```

This will initialize the HTTP-Server timeout to be 5 minutes.